# Create List with object and strings

Tags: java

I want to create list with object like 
i.e. for every object there is entries of two strings that related to him.

i try to find in the net some kind of example and maybe I should to it with class
but I not sure how to connect the object to the strings.

```
<object,String,String>

Like 
Object1 String1 String10
Object2 String2 String3
```

Comment: Can you connect two strings with a class?

Comment: You could use one ``String`` and separate it into two by using a ``line.separator``. That way you can use a ``Map`` to link your ``Object`` to the ``String``.

Comment: Or to arrays of `String`s with size `2` if joining is not applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what you want, which is not entirely clear. You could either have a class containing two strings e.g.

```
class Pair {
    public String a,b;
}
```

And then have a `List<Pair> myList = new List<>();`

**EDIT**: Just saw your edit - probably don't want this one, unless you updated your class to contain the object as a field also e.g. `public object him; public String a,b;`

Or, if you have an existing object that you want associated with each pair of strings, which it sounds like you might have, you'll want to use a `Map`, like `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<Him, Pair> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

See [the javadocs for HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: Thanks Jeff I read About hashMap but its not helping here since you can for example use two string but how I relate between them

Comment: In the example I give, the `Him` type would be the `object` in your example, and the `Pair` object contains the strings. To get from the object to the strings you just call `myMap.get(someObject);`